# Front audio jack from a DG965SS Intel motherboard doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I have recently installed Windows 7 on my PC with a DG965SS Intel motherboard, and after updating the OS through to the end, none of the front audio panel connectors work (for headphones or microphone).

I tried downloading the latest drivers from Intel [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop+Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+965+Express+Chipset+Family+Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Desktop+Board+DG965SS), but after installation nothing seems to change. I also tried downloading and installing the Realtek High Definition Audio drivers since those came in the original drivers CD (which doesn't work any more in Windows 7), with no results.

There is no record of them even existing (I used to have two reproduction devices):

[image]

Do any of you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Intel has no Windows 7 drivers for that discontinued motherboard ([see here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18246&lang=eng)), and won't be supplying any.  But you can get Windows 7 compatible Realtek drivers directly from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) (currently at version R2.40) that should get you your High Definition Audio Codecs working again, including what's needed to use the front panel jacks.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, the words on the original post weren't too precise. I already tried installing the realtek drivers, it didn't work.

Comment: OK I think I figured out what's going on.  That board doesn't have Realtek audio, it has IDT (Sigmatel) Audio.  You can get the latest version here: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=13706&lang=eng (you can't get them directly form Sigmatel) - But it doesn't support Windows 7, so you'll have to force it in.  I found some instructions here: http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/1804-intel-idt-audio-driver-will-not-install.html that seem to be what you'll need.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't even need to force that driver. You've saved my life, thank you.

Comment: Even better! :)  I'll file that away in my brain, as we sold a bunch of those SS boards back in the day.